# Behaviour of Solutions to $x^2y'' + \alpha xy'+ \beta y = 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the Euler equation $x^2y'' + \alpha xy' + \beta y = 0$.
>   Find conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that:
>
> 1. All solutions approach zero as $x \rightarrow 0$
> 2. All solutions are bounded as $x \rightarrow 0$
> 3. All solutions approach zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$
> 4. All solutions are bounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$
> 5. All solutions are bounded both as $x \rightarrow 0$ and $x \rightarrow \infty$

I am having trouble solving the problem. It must obviously have to do with the solutions to the indicial equation $ r^2 + (\alpha - 1)r + \beta= 0 \implies r = \dfrac{1 - \alpha
\pm \sqrt {(\alpha - 1)^2 - 4\beta^2}}{2} $. When these roots are identical or complex the solutions involve an $\ln x$ term the limit of which when $x \to 0$ is undefined I think? So my feeble argument is that the solutions for $r$ should be distinct to begin with? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

A logarithmic term, if present, only changes the behaviour as $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$ when $\text{Re}(r) = 0$.  That is, if $\text{Re}(r) \ne 0$ then both 
$x^r$ and $x^r \log(x)$ have the same limit or lack of limit as $x \to \infty$ and as $x \to 0$.  I don't know what that "or complex" is doing there: in the Euler equation a logarithmic term only appears when the roots are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It's literally worked out here:
http://banach.millersville.edu/~bob/math365/homework/boycediprima/sec05.05.pdf

Comment: Note this is question 5.4.29 from Boyce's elementary diff eqns version 11 global edition - exercise 27 in the American edition.